# Update Javadoc version and author across all files?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I need to keep in sync the `@version` tag of all class Javadocs in my project, as well as the `@author` tag. However I don't know an easy way to do this.

Is there a plugin (preferably a maven plugin) that could accomplish this? And no, the maven-release plugin will not do this for me.

Comment: I would do a find and replace in my IDE for the author. I wouldn't change the author unless the name the author would like to use has changed. I suspect the @version would change more often, so often I wouldn't include it in the javadoc content. Instead I would include the version in the directory/jar where the javadoc is stored (like oracle/sun does).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I use `@version` is, in conjunction with `@since`. IMHO, I think `@version` represents version of software when this class was *modified* and `@since` represents the version of the software when this file/class was *created*.

On `@author`, my policy is each developer who has ever contributed to that class (in some major way) should append his/her name.

So, if you see all these processes are manual and need to be done by Class creator/modifier at the time of coding. And, obviously you will have unequal version of files. And, I guess that makes sense.

I would like to listen if someone differs on this.

Comment: I think that I can settle for this as a standard. Now to just manually update all the @author tags across my project...

Answer (score 2):

Of course there's a maven way to do it, but it's very unusual:

define your src/main/java folder as `<resource>`, with a fixed outputDirectory. Then reconfigure javadoc and jar plugins, something like this:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <targetPath>sources</targetPath>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourcepath>${project.build.outputDirectory}/sources</sourcepath>
            </configuration>
            <!-- other config stripped -->
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>sources/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <!-- other config stripped -->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now you can use placeholders in your source files and interpolate them with maven properties (see [maven filtering](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/) for reference)

Comment: Just curious that when deployment plugin  will create JavaDoc, would it  see the filtered files or it would  straight look into `src/main/java`?  I mean I never tried this, hopefully it  works. I  am a bit dubious.

Comment: @Nishant The deploy plugin doesn't create javadoc, the javadoc plugin does. And we're telling the javadoc plugin where the files are.

Comment: One thing to note is that this approach will make IntelliJ IDEA think of source files as of resources, and it will not use proper completion and other IDE features on those source files.

Comment: @Suseika if that's the case I'd say that's a bug of IntelliJ

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd In this configuration you basically say: "There are resources, not sources in src/main/java directory". IntelliJ just does what is said in pom.xml. It is not a bug in IntelliJ, but rather a bad way to accomplish the task with `<resources>` reconfiguring. Replacer plugin is probably what one should use to modify sources at build time: https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/

Comment: @Suseika No, I basically say src/main/java is both source and resource. There is no maven convention I am aware of that says a directory can't be both source and resource. IntelliJ is a bit strict in the assumptions it makes and that's not always right. E.g. if it finds the aspectj-maven-plugin in the build, it switches the entire compilation from javac to ajc, which is just plain wrong. I'd say it's wrong here, too. And the plugin you link to was alpha at best at the time I answered this question. Feel free to add an answer now that features it.