# Maven, Subversion, Javadocs

Tags: java, svn, maven, javadoc

is there any way to modify Javadocs @version value and add revision number of the file automaticly on SVN repository?

example template
@version $v rev. $rev

and output
@version v2.1 rev. 74321

update:
i want to add revision numbers and "maybe" if it would be possible, tag-names as versions

Comment: someone asked almost the same thing a moment ago. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557747/update-javadoc-version-and-author-across-all-files well ignore it, it's different.

Comment: "like that", but not same question ;) i want to add revision numbers and "maybe" if it would be possible, tag-names as versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Subversion keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) to substitute the revision number. For instance:

```
/**
 * Get the <tt>foo</tt> value.
 *
 * @version $Revision$
 */
class Foo
{
    ...
}
```

However, you'll need to set the `svn:keywords` property on each of the files for which you want to do that expansion. e.g.:

```
$ svn propset svn:keywords "Revision" Foo.java
property 'svn:keywords' set on 'Foo.java'
```